# Cortar párrafo en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, pipe

tengo un párrafo obtenido de una base de datos mediante una api en Laravel, esta tiene html, un ejemplo `<p> un texto del párrafo</p>`
Alguien sabe de algún pipe , o algún otro método, que me deje por ejemplo seleccionar 10 palabras del párrafo, y que esto no corte el html, es posible esto?
Es decir, en el ejemplo que puse, si pongo que solo muestre 2 palabras quedaría: `<p> un texto`
Esto estaría mal porque no estaría cerrando la etiqueta

.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar dos variables. Una que guarde el valor original y la otra, que esté limpia y recortada.

```
  mostrarCompleto = false;

  textoHTML =
    "<p> un texto del párrafo de mas de 10 letras que sera recortado para mostrar un muy bonito resumen</p>";
  arrayTextoLimpio = this.textoHTML
    .replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "")
    .split(" ")
    .splice(0, 10)
    .join(" ");
```

Y en tu html creas con `*ngIf` dos secciones, una que renderize el html y otra que muestre el texto en resumen:

```
<span *ngIf="mostrarCompleto" >
  <div [innerHTML]=" textoHTML"></div>

  <a 
  (click)="mostrarCompleto = !mostrarCompleto" 
  title="Mostrar texto completo"
  href="javascript:void(0)" >...Ocultar</a>
</span>

<span *ngIf="!mostrarCompleto">

  {{  arrayTextoLimpio}} <a 
  (click)="mostrarCompleto = !mostrarCompleto" 
  title="Mostrar texto completo"
  href="javascript:void(0)" >...</a>
</span>
```

Ahora solo basta dar click para que la variable `mostrarCompleto` cambie de estado.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/recortar-texto?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias Legna, voy a hacerlo como decís, aunque en el texto 
<p> un texto del párrafo de mas de 10 letras que sera recortado para mostrar un muy bonito resumen</p>
Si por ejemplo la palabra "mostrar" estuviese en negrita, al mostrarlo como texto limpio no sería mas negrita...Pero igual voy a usarlo como decís. Gracias

Comment: Puedes modifcar el regex para que no elimine las negritas. Por ejemplo, primero sustituyes todas esas etiquetas por un balor generico tudo (**--AquiVaMiNegrita--**), y despues quitas las demas etiquetas. En un tercer paso conviertes de nuevo las negritas. Lo puedes hacer programáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que te interesa es el texto de los datos obtenidos y no el HTML, puedes usar `strip_tags()` sobre el texto extraido. Luego separar las palabras para solo extraer las N primeras, y reconstruir el texto final.

```
$data="<p> un texto del párrafo</p>";
$texto=trim(strip_tags($data)); // un texto del párrafo
$palabras=explode(" ",$texto); // palabras en un array [un,texto,del,parrafo]
$extract=array_slice($palabras,0,2); // las primeras 2 palabras [un,texto]
$newtext=implode(" ",$extract); // "un texto"
```

Comment: Claro, pero lo que necesito seria como un resumen del párrafo,  está bien lo que decís, pero perdería los estilos...quiero decir el html.